# sed + remove char after specific word

Tags: linux, sed

I want to delete the last "." only if "." exist after "usa" word

my sed command only removed the last "." ,

but what need to add to the sed syntax (a rule) in order to remove the "." only after "usa" word

```
 host 10.1.23.86 | awk '{print $NF}'
 sho4.il.usa.


 host 10.1.23.86 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s'/.$//'
 sho4.il.usa
```

what need to add  in the sed in order to remove the "." only after "usa" word?

Comment: `sed -e 's/\(\.usa\)\./\1/'`

Comment: Note that `sho4.il.usa.` is a valid domain name. `sho4.il.usa` is just an abbreviation of the full `sho4.il.usa.` domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `usa` in the expression. You also need to escape `.` in order to match only the dot itself instead of any char.

```
sed s'/usa\.$/usa/'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do most of what `sed` can do, so it's rare you need to pipe them together.

```
host 10.1.23.86 | awk '{sub(/usa\.$/, "usa", $NF); print $NF}'
```

Comment: You can also avoid a second pipe with `sed`.  `host 10.1.23.86 | sed -e 's/.*\ \(.*\)$/\1/; s/\.$//'`